# No matching function for call to error when reading from a valid file

Tags: c++, filestream

I have the following data in a file:

```
0001 O 100 102.30
0001 O 101 333.22
0001 O 102 679.13
0001 P 103 513.36
0001 P 104 700.94
```

With the following code:

```
vector<string> customerID;
vector<char> transactionType;
vector<string> transactionNumber;
vector<double> amount;

string cID, tT, tN, amnt;

for(;infile2 >> cID >> tT >> tN >> amnt;){
    customerID.push_back(cID);
    transactionType.push_back(tT);
    transactionNumber.push_back(tN);
    amount.push_back(amnt);
}
```

and the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<char>::push_back(std::string&)'
error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<double>::push_back(std::string&)'
```

Is it assuming every data item is a string ?
How can i fix this ?

Comment: just use string vectors, then convert the values as needed.

Comment: @redFIVE That is a workaround the main issue but I still would like to know why C++ is being stupid

Comment: You're trying to push a `string` into a `char` and a `double` vector.

Comment: @Adam No, I'm pushing a char in to a char and a double in to a double vector. Look at my file data. The second item is a character and the last item is a double number.

Comment: what do you think `string cID, tT, tN, amnt;` means

Comment: No, `tT` is a `string`. You declare it as such. Yet you want to push_back into a `vector<char>`

Comment: I'm sorry, I understand my mistake, thank you

Comment: C++ is not being "stupid". You have strings, read into them, then try to push them back into vectors of not-strings. Is C++ assuming all your strings are strings? Yes; yes, it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is.  You're reading four strings, and you're converting any of them to anything else.  C++ doesn't provide implicit conversions from `std::string` to non-string types.

The easiest way to fix your problem is to read `tT` and `amnt` as `char` and `double`.  Simply declare your variables as

```
std::string cID, tN;
char tT;
double amnt;
```

and it should work.  Alternately, you can read them as strings and convert them.

Answer (score 1):

As written, you are using four `string` variables when reading. You can correct it by declaring variables of the appropriate types.

```
vector<string> customerID;
vector<char> transactionType;
vector<string> transactionNumber;
vector<double> amount;

string cID, tN;
char tT;
double amnt;

for(;infile2 >> cID >> tT >> tN >> amnt;){
    customerID.push_back(cID);
    transactionType.push_back(tT);
    transactionNumber.push_back(tN);
    amount.push_back(amnt);
}
```